# Custom Wordpress Core upgrade through wp-cli

Tags: php, upgrade, core, core-modifications

I'm trying to do a custom wordpress core upgrade through wp-cli, theres an GUI upgrade hang issue in kubernetes when AWS EFS storage is used. For me `wp core upgrade` works great. I need somekind of binding to the upgrade button in the gui, when clicked it should invoke the custom_upgrade.php script which will do shell execution. I'm pretty new to php and wordpress. Here's a sample script provided by mwithheld: `https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/1924`

Comment: Is this a replacement for [your other question from yesterday](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/291834/wordpress-update-hangs-on-aws-efs)? I have answered the command execution part via PHP in [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/256726/is-it-possible-to-use-wp-cli-via-php-framework/291803#291803), but I wouldn't recommend doing that. Fixing the cause instead of treating the symptom makes more sense IMHO.

Comment: @swissspidy You are right about fixing the cause, i was trying this custom php script solution and found about the timouts from openshift (Kubernetes) router (haproxy), increased the timeout and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a php script that can execute wp-cli, Keep the file in wp-admin/ folder and visit www.example-wordpress.com/wp-admin/execute_cli.php to run the script. This is just for test purposes and not a good way to use.

execute_cli.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
echo "<PRE>\n";

if(!defined('STDIN'))  define('STDIN',  fopen('php://stdin',  'r'));
if(!defined('STDOUT')) define('STDOUT', fopen('php://stdout', 'w'));
if(!defined('STDERR')) define('STDERR', fopen('php://stdout', 'w'));

echo "Started\n\n";
$return_status = false;
$output = array();
//$executable = '/path/to/php-executable -c /path/to/php.ini -d error_reporting="E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE" -d memory_limit="2048M" -d max_execution_time=43200 wp-cli.phar ';
//Redirect stdERR so we see warnings/errors
$suffix = ' 2>&1';
//echo 'Built executable='.$executable."\n";

//$command = 'user delete johnsmithfake --network --yes';
$command = 'wp core update';
//$full_command = $executable.$command.$suffix;
$full_command = $command.$suffix;

echo "About to execute command=\n{$full_command}\n";
exec($full_command, $output, $return_var);

echo "---------------\n";
echo implode("\n", $output)."\n";
echo "---------------\n";
echo "Return status (false/0 is success)=".($return_status?1:0)."\n";

echo "\nDone</PRE>\n";
```